# understanding jquery closest()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking at [this plugin](https://cdn.rawgit.com/vanderlee/dropmenu/f1bddb4c7f7a30391622139b1b2d9bc39beb6cb0/jquery.dropmenu.js) and trying to understand how the _handle_mousedown event works.

It uses the expression: `$(event.target).closest(that.element).is(that.element)`

It seems to me that the `.closest(that.element).is(that.element)` should always return true as that.element should always be the same as itself.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like this is just checking for the existence of `that.element`. I would read the code you posted as equivalent to: `$(event.target).closest(that.element).length > 0`

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I tested `$(document).closest(undefined).is(undefined)` does indeed return false.

Comment: I reposted the comment as an answer, so you can accept it if it fully answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a way to check for the existence of an element.

The code you posted:

```
$(event.target).closest(that.element).is(that.element)
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
$(event.target).closest(that.element).length === 1
```

Comment: Outside of the original OP, I prefer to use `$(event.target).closest(that.element).length == 1` because jQuery is a 3rd party resource, it's possible (however unlikely) that `closest()` could be changed to return more than one element in future versions.

Comment: In the context of the OP it won't matter, because `that.element` will only be a single element itself (unless it's a selector string, which it doesn't look like is).